# When the function is increasing/decreasing in an interval.

Tags: functions, derivatives

If f(x) is decreasing in the interval (a,b), a<0<b and f'(0)=0 then should I write f(x) is decreasing in the interval (a,b) - {0} ?
My book does not include the "-{0}" part so I just wanted to confirm, and to know the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  We are assured that the function is decreasing in the interval $(a,b)$.  Why would you want to remove $0$?

Comment: Just to say, the vanishing of the derivative doesn't tell you much.  $-x^3$ is strictly decreasing on the entire line, for instance.

Comment: Because if f'(0)=0 then it's not increasing or decreasing at that point. But i guess the answer below clears things up

Comment: Again, $f(x)=-x^3$ is strictly decreasing at $x=0$, despite the fact that $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Why exclude the $0$? To be decreasing just means that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$ for $x_1<x_2$. A zero of the derivative is not a sufficient condition to have a maximum or minimum, for example as Lulu say, the typical example is the function $x^3$, which is always increasing and verifies that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: These days, it's much more common for "decreasing" to mean $x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)≥f(x_2)$.  And the OP had the condition $f'(0)=0$, not $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you. 